# Xamarin Forms - strange behaviour on iOS after updating Visual Studio from 2017 to 2019

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

After updating Visual Studio from 2017 to 2019, Visual Studio for Mac to from 2017 2019 and "Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK" from 12.4.0.64 to 13.10.0.17 something weird appeared on iOS applications. When user opens new page by:

```
 await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(page, animated);
```

then extra padding appears at top (about 50px), that is transparent - there user see part of previous page underneath (with rounded corners). Moreover page has margin left and right (about 3 px), page has rounded corners.
The same code in Visual Studio 2017 displays page with 100% cover of screen. In 2019 is about 90%. It looks like a pop up.
How to get 100% cover in 2019 version?

Comment: Hi , that's changed by Apple in iOS 13 .

Answer (score 0):

Apple has changed the default presentation of modal pages on iOS 13 in line with what you have described.

However, this behavior doesn't appear in the Xamarin.Forms by default. You probably have some custom renderer or plugin that is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

That's be changed from iOS 13 by Apple . If need the same effect of previous navigation .

There is a easy **workaround** here . Using `PushAsync` to replace `PushModalAsync` as follow :

```
await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page, animated);
```

If not needing `NavigationBar` or `BackButton` the same as `PushModalAsync` , you can hide them as follow :

```
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(itemDetailPage, false); //Hide BackButton

NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(itemDetailPage,false);//Hide NavigationBar
```